# Type of (.) . (.)

Tags: haskell, types

How can one infer that the type of `(.) . (.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c`?

(What I thought and which is obviously wrong is: The type of `(.)` is `(t2->t3) -> (t1->t2) -> t1 -> t3`, which should be the same as `(t2->t3) -> [(t1->t2) -> (t1->t3)]` (using also `[]{}` for readability). Hence, the type of `(.) . (.)` should be something like `{(b2->b3) -> [(b1->b2) -> (b1->b3)]} -> {(a2->a3) -> [(a1->a2) -> (a1->a3)]}` which requires `(b2->b3)` to match `[(a1->a2) -> (a1->a3)]`...

But this never leads to the desired type.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `(.) . (.)` means `(.) (.) (.)`. To obtain its type let's start from:

```
(.) :: (t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
(.)    (.)        :: ???
```

Let's alpha-convert the type of second `(.)` to `(a2 -> a3) -> (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a3`. This type is `t2 -> t3`, so we get

```
t2 = a2 -> a3
t3 = (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a3
```

Hence,

```
(.) (.) :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3    with the above t2,t3
(.) (.) :: (t1 -> a2 -> a3) -> t1 -> (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a3
```

Now,

```
(.) (.) :: (t1 -> a2 -> a3) -> t1 -> (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a3
(.) (.)    (.)              :: ???
```

Let the third `(.)` have type `(b2 -> b3) -> (b1 -> b2) -> b1 -> b3`. 
This is `t1 -> a2 -> a3`, so we get

```
t1 = b2 -> b3
a2 -> a3 = (b1 -> b2) -> b1 -> b3
```

hence

```
t1 = b2 -> b3
a2 = b1 -> b2
a3 = b1 -> b3
```

Concluding:

```
(.) (.) (.) :: t1 -> (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a3   with the above t1,a2,a3
(.) (.) (.) :: (b2 -> b3) -> (a1 -> b1 -> b2) -> a1 -> b1 -> b3
```

which is your expected type

```
               (b  -> c ) -> (a  -> a1 -> b ) -> a  -> a1 -> c
```

once type variables are alpha-converted.

Comment: `t1` in your second text block should be `t2`.

Comment: You are right, this is how is has to be done. Thank you very much :D